# How to make my Git history cleaner by removing merge commits?

Tags: git, github

I have a Git [repo](https://github.com/OldEngineer1911/AoC_2015) and I don't know how to make my history clean. I would like to follow rebase [rules](https://blog.algolia.com/master-git-rebase/) and keep my history clean.

I tried to find solution to my problem on Stack Overflow, but none of the solutions here suit my case.

My current state:

[image: git history]

My expectation is to avoid creating "Merge pull request #1 from OldEngineer1911/develop". I don't know why is there this merge?

Current flow is:

1. Implement something
2. Make 1 to n commits
3. Rebase and squash commits
4. Create Merge request in GitHub
5. Merge commit in GitHub as an administrator

Question 1: Is there any way, how can I avoid commit message "Merge pull request #1 from OldEngineer1911/develop"?

Question 2: Can I somehow "repair" current history, to make it clear?

Comment: Do you use feature branches? Usually if you follow https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/, your history stays clean and concise. I rebase feature branch to the latest master before creating a PR. When merging PR back to master/main branch, there are multiple options, I choose Squash Merge option and it creates one commit on master.

Comment: I create branch, this branch is from develop and aiming to develop. After each successful merge to develop I am merging also develop to master. Maybe the problem is, that I am using develop, even if I am the only one contributor? Thank you for introduction link. This should solve my Q1. I will try to follow this flow in future!

Comment: Merge commits aren’t messy. To me they’re very helpful to understand the true history of the repo.

Comment: Maybe it is wrong question, but what do you mean by "true" history? In future I would like to connect each commit with some task / issue number, which should be described deeper in github history. So everyone could look why I added this part of code. But maybe I am wrong and I could do it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad that my explanation helped you. Just converting it to answer along with few additional points.

For question 2, it is better to leave it as it is.

---

Usually if you follow https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/, your history stays clean and concise.

I rebase feature branch to the latest master before creating a PR.

When merging PR back to master/main branch, there are multiple options on the web site UI, I choose Squash Merge option and it creates one commit on master.

Yes, usually I name feature branches to reflect the work instead of just `develop`, f.ex. `oauth2_support` or `bug_fix_k22899`. Once PR is merged, I delete the feature branch.